# How do I apply a z transformation based on unique values of a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Ford Focus','Ford Focus','Ford Focus','Ford Focus','Ford Focus','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Audi A4','Audi A4','Audi A4','Audi A4','Audi A4','Audi A4','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [35,12,3,64,234,90,27012,31200,22000,25000,27000,35000,22100,25340,27012,31200,22000,25000,27000,35000,22100,25340,27012,31200,22100,25340,27012,31200,76341]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand','Price'])
```

I would like to apply z-transformation to the Price values, by each car's brand name.

For instance, my desired output for the Honda Civic is as follows:

```
df3 = df[df['Brand']=='Honda Civic']
df3[['z_scores']] = df3[['Price']].apply(zscore)

    Brand           Price   z_scores
0   Honda Civic     35      -0.488170
1   Honda Civic     12      -0.783641
2   Honda Civic     3       -0.899261
3   Honda Civic     64      -0.115619
4   Honda Civic     234     2.068300
```

However, I would like to do this without splitting the dataframe manually. I tried the following:

```
df1['z_scores'] =''
for i in df1['Brand'].unique():
    df1[['z_scores']] = df1[['Price']].apply(zscore)
df1.head()

    Brand           Price   z_scores
0   Honda Civic     35      -1.519706
1   Honda Civic     12      -1.521221
2   Honda Civic     3       -1.521814
3   Honda Civic     64      -1.517795
4   Honda Civic     234     -1.506595
```

This clearly did not work, because the result is the same as when I apply it to the entire dataframe, see below:

```
df2['z_scores'] =''
df2[['z_scores']] = df2[['Price']].apply(zscore)

    Brand           Price   z_scores
0   Honda Civic     35      -1.519706
1   Honda Civic     12      -1.521221
2   Honda Civic     3       -1.521814
3   Honda Civic     64      -1.517795
4   Honda Civic     234     -1.506595
```

Does anyone know I can apply the z-transformation to the car Prices by each car's brand name, without manually splitting the dataframe and then merging it?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: I don't understand this: "only based on that respective car brand's values, independently of all other car brands."

Comment: Updated based on your feedback!

Comment: @MayankPorwal Added!

Comment: @arkadiy Please check my answer.

Comment: @MayankPorwal thank you! you rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SciPy.zscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) with [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
In [4457]: from scipy.stats import zscore

In [4459]: df['z_scores'] = df.groupby('Brand').Price.transform(zscore)

In [4460]: df
Out[4460]: 
             Brand  Price  z_scores
0      Honda Civic     35 -0.488170
1      Honda Civic     12 -0.783641
2      Honda Civic      3 -0.899261
3      Honda Civic     64 -0.115619
4      Honda Civic    234  2.068300
5      Honda Civic     90  0.218392
6   Toyota Corolla  27012  0.043589
7   Toyota Corolla  31200  1.054956
8   Toyota Corolla  22000 -1.166766
9   Toyota Corolla  25000 -0.442292
10  Toyota Corolla  27000  0.040691
11  Toyota Corolla  35000  1.972623
12  Toyota Corolla  22100 -1.142617
13  Toyota Corolla  25340 -0.360185
14      Ford Focus  27012 -0.007427
15      Ford Focus  31200  0.947510
16      Ford Focus  22000 -1.150250
17      Ford Focus  25000 -0.466198
18      Ford Focus  27000 -0.010163
19      Ford Focus  35000  1.813976
20      Ford Focus  22100 -1.127448
21         Audi A4  25340 -0.474371
22         Audi A4  27012 -0.373373
23         Audi A4  31200 -0.120395
24         Audi A4  22100 -0.670084
25         Audi A4  25340 -0.474371
26         Audi A4  27012 -0.373373
27         Audi A4  31200 -0.120395
28         Audi A4  76341  2.606363
```